# Transición en un dropdown no funciona

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando añadir una transición a este dropdown:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Select</button>
    <div class="dropdown_content">
      <a>1</a> 
      <a>2</a>
      <a>3</a>
      <a>4</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}

.dropbtn {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #888;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown_content {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 13px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}

.dropdown_content a {
    display: block;
    color: #555;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    transition: ease 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown_content a:hover {
    background: #0092ED;
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown_content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
    height: auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background: #0092ED;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Sé que el navegador no puede calcular una transición de `display: none;` a `display: block;` pero en este caso estoy cambiando el alto del **`dropdown_content`** y no entiendo por qué no está funcionando.

También os lo dejo en **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0x4qems/1/)** para ahorrar el copia y pega.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar **max-height** en lugar de **height** y establecer un alto fijo a **max-height**

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}

.dropbtn {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #888;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown_content {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -2px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    max-height: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}

.dropdown_content a {
    display: block;
    color: #555;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    transition: ease 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown_content a:hover {
    background: #0092ED;
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown_content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
    max-height: 500px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background: #0092ED;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Select</button>
    <div class="dropdown_content">
      <a>1</a> 
      <a>2</a>
      <a>3</a>
      <a>4</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Edwin! Probé eso antes, pero no entiendo por qué en su momento no funcionó, seguramente tendría algo por ahí suelto